# How to extract data from this JSON ?

Tags: php, arrays, json, extract

I got this JSON but have to clue how to extract data from them.

I tried `$data['success'][0]['success']` and it worked

However I want something like $getPlayerLimit and returns 1000

```
Array
(
    [result] => success
    [source] => Array
        (
            [0] => getPlayerLimit
            [1] => getPlayerCount
        )

    [success] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [result] => success
                    [source] => getPlayerLimit
                    [success] => 1000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [result] => success
                    [source] => getPlayerCount
                    [success] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I dont't know how to extract data from this JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array can be iterated over to find the value of `getPlayerLimit`

```
    foreach($data['success'] as $item)
    {
        if($item['source'] == 'getPlayerLimit')
        {
            /*
                $item looks like:

                Array
                (
                    [result] => success
                    [source] => getPlayerLimit
                    [success] => 1000
                )
            */
            echo 'player limit is: ' . $item['success'];
        }
    }
```